# Lost colour scheme in TMUX when using Vim

Tags: vim, tmux

I have a molokai colour scheme for vim which loads fine from shell. I've just installed tmux but have lost my colour settings. From reading other posts I found these settings for 256 mode but I must be missing a step. I'm on MacVim 7.3 and used brew for tmux

Here are my config settings

~/.tmux.conf

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

~/.bashrc

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm"
```

I ran

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

then either tmux or tmux -2 and I get the plain white screen when running vi. Any tips welcome

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set -g default-terminal "whatever"` is a tmux command: it has nothing to do in `~/.bashrc`.

`set` is a genuine command of your shell but it doesn't follow the same syntax and should spit an error upon initialization anyway.

1. Remove that line from `~/.bashrc`.
2. Go to the prefs of your terminal emulator and set it to use `xterm-256color`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
TERM="screen-256color" vim
```

or

```
TERM="xterm" vim
```

and see which one has colors, and use that in `.bashrc`.